# jQuery jqModal confirm dialog callback issue

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

Using the code from the jqModal website, section FUN! Overrides:
http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples
(I edited the code to make use of a callback function)

```
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes')
          (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}

$().ready(function() {
  $('#confirm').jqm({overlay: 88, modal: true, trigger: false});

  // trigger a confirm whenever links of class alert are pressed.
  $('a.confirm').click(function() { 
    confirm('About to visit: '+this.href+' !',callbackfunction); 
    return false;
  });
});

function callbackfunction()
{
 console.log("callback triggered");
}
```

The problem: each time when the confirm function is called, the callback gets triggered incrementally, so when I click the 2nd time, the handler gets executed 2 times, the 3th time, 3 times and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because each time you call the confirm function, you add a new 'click' event handler.

Comment: i see :), but i dont really know how to change the code to make it work like it should. I have multiple confirm dialogs that should call different callbacks

Comment: You just need to set them up once, e.g. on document ready, then just change the message text and show when you call e.g. the confirm method. Or, set a boolean to indicate that you've already added the handler, and don't add it again.

Comment: yes, indeed but when i define the click handler on document ready level, the callbackfunction() that would be executed is not variable, unless i define a variable specific for this that is changed when the click handler of the anchor is called.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply unbinding the click event in the confirm box before binding the new, updated callback.  In my example below, note the confirm() function and the **unbind** of any bound **click** events *before* binding the new callback.  Perhaps his example code should really be:

```
function confirm(msg,callback) {
  $('#confirm')
    .jqmShow()
    .find('p.jqmConfirmMsg')
      .html(msg)
    .end()
    .find(':submit:visible')
    .unbind('click')
      .click(function(){
        if(this.value == 'yes')
          (typeof callback == 'string') ?
            window.location.href = callback :
            callback();
        $('#confirm').jqmHide();
      });
}
```

Some time has past since your original post but perhaps this can be of use to someone in the future.  jqModal is really quite great.